# how do i change state value before fetching data?

Tags: reactjs

When I enter "Enter" key, I want to change my value of input field such that there is "+" in place of empty space and at the same time I want to fetch the data but when I am unable to do so. What could be the solution?

```
const [inputdata, setInputdata] = useState("");
const [searchData, setSearchData] = useState("");

 const inputHandler = (e) => {
    setInputdata(e.target.value);
  };
  const handleFetch = async (e) => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      setSearchData(inputdata.replace(/\s/g, "+"));
      const url = `https://google-search3.p.rapidapi.com/api/v1/search/q=${searchData}`;
      const raw_data = await fetch(url, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          "x-rapidapi-key": api_key,
        },
      });
      const data = await raw_data.json();
      console.log(data);
    }
}
return(
<input
            type="text"
            value={inputdata}
            onKeyPress={handleFetch}
            onChange={inputHandler}
          />
)
```

Comment: I want to pass the searchData in the link, so I wrote `setSearchadata` and then fetched, but it fetches null data

Comment: why did you define `searchData` as state? why don't you define it as normal variable?

Comment: yeah it worked as a regular variable but why it did not worked as a state variable?

Comment: greate. good job.

Answer (score 0):

If it works fine as a normal variable keep it that way, but it seems it might have broke because you are crossing states to fix you should do:

```
setInputdata(inputdata.replace(/\s/g, "+"));
setSearchData(inputdata);
```